# when I enter a correct value 1-99 I still get an exception

Tags: java

```
public static String getQtyInput(String prompt) throws Exception
{
    String qtyValue;
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {       
        qtyValue = getStringInput(prompt);
        counter++;      
    } while (counter < 3);

    if (Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) > 1 || Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) < 99) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input! \n Must enter 1-99");
    }

    return qtyValue;
}
```

Comment: Show me `x` for which `x>1 || x<99` will be evaluated to false.

Comment: @Pshemo does not need to be used && ?

Comment: @KickButtowski It depends on what OP wants. General idea I want to show OP is that `||` creates sum of two number sets, `&&` creates intersection. Both can be used here (but we would need to add negation with `$$`)..

Comment: *with `&&` (instead of `$$` - I may need glasses)

Answer (score 3):

Think about what you're trying to check for. A number in the range 1 to 99 is correct, so you only want to show the exception when the number is *outside* that range. So in other words, when it's *lower* (<) than one or *higher* (>) than 99.

So you need to rewrite your if-statement to:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) > 99)
```

Comment: I still get the exception and at the end of the third count I get the message "Cannot format given object as a number" Any Ideas?

Comment: What are you entering as a `String`?

Comment: Entering a number between 1-99

Comment: You need to check that qtyValue variable to see if it indeed is a String object and contains a value in the set [1, 99]. Please reply if you are still having problems after using the debugger.

Comment: I'm still having problems I use the debugger but it shows that it is returning the value I enter. I don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are still getting an exception actually depends on what your `getStringInput(string)` method returns in the third iteration of the loop (i.e., when counter is 2).

Try to print the value of `qtyValue` after the loop ends, and you might find some unexpected value there, which might be resulting in the Exception.

Debug your code, or just add this line after while-loop to see the result:

```
System.out.println(qtyValue);
```

And DO change your if-condition to the following if you mean to throw exception for numbers strictly between 1 and 99:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(qtyValue) > 99)
```

Comment: I try your debt, I got the value I was entering so I'm not sure why It's not breaking the loop. I appreciate your help, I got stuck on this and this assignment is due in 2 hours.